# Postgres one to many

Tags: sql, postgresql

## My Question

Is option B sane?

I've googled it about a million times and I think my biggest problem is not knowing how to ask in a way that google understands lol. I need to create one to many relationship in a Postgres DB and would like some advise before I actually execute on this.

## Option A

In the past I've done this sort of thing with an additional primary -> foreign table. This is , from what I understand, the standard method of creating a one to many in PG.

```
+-------+-------+
|   D   |   A   |
+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+
|   D   |   B   |
+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+
|   D   |   C   |
+-------+-------+
```

## Option B (?)

Most of my SQL experience is with MySQL and I've seen some really cool stuff from postgres and I was wondering if it would be possible to join tables if the D record itself held on to the foreign keys like so.

```
table : A
+-------+-------+-------+
|   id  |   a   |   b   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   100 |   2   |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   101 |   2   |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+

table : B
+-------+-------+-------+
|   id  |   a   |   b   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   45  |   5   |   6   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   46  |   7   |   10  |
+-------+-------+-------+

table : C
+-------+-------+-------+
|   id  |   a   |   b   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   12  |   5   |   6   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   13  |   3   |   9   |
+-------+-------+-------+

table : D
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   id  |   A   |   B   |   C   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |100,101|45,46  |12,13  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

EDIT
It should be mentioned that this table will be MASSIVE. It will be making hundreds of records per second in the near future so storage space and read / write speed are all pretty important.

Comment: "Sane" is usually applied to people, or at least animate objects.  "Good idea".  No.  You should have separate rows, either 2 rows in a single junction table, or three separate junction tables, depending on what you want to achieve.  Storing numbers in a string field (which is what your question suggests) is generally a bad idea.

Comment: One-to-many is easy - just add a foreign key field to the "many" table that references the item on the "one" table.

Comment: I'm going to repeat what @GordonLinoff said because it's just that important. Don't store multiple records in a single field ever for any reason. It's always a bad idea. It's also never a good idea. The good news is you will realize how bad it is as soon as you start writing sql to deal with it.

Comment: Pretty sure you guys have answered my question. I'll leave it open in case someone can prove you wrong hahaha. 

The idea came to me after discovering that PG could store JSON objects and actually query the stored JSON. I was hoping I could use a legit join on stored JSON xD.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on many things:

- You have to do a join sql with array comparison, which is not difficult. Inserting or updating the record is also straight forward.
  [Official Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)
  E.g `SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE 10000 = ANY (pay_by_quarter);`
- The main problem arrives is how much the postgresql driver in your application can support, if you use ORM such as Hibernate in Java, you can have a difficult time.
- The third issue is the lock condition when applications try to update the same row which would otherwise being two separate rows. So if the table is not so big, it doesn't make sense to trade between size and speed.